# Change string in IDWriteTextLayout without create

Tags: c++

I am trying to use FW1Fontwrapper and do not wish to create and release the IDWriteTextLayout in every render loop. In doing so, I want to update the old one. However, I can set everything... EXCEPT the actual string. How do I change the string? Where is it hidden?

EDIT1 FOR SECONDARY QUESTIONING:

```
//if anything in the font changed needs changing
            if (_cFont.fontSize != fontSize || 0 != wcscmp(_cFont.fontText, text))
            {
                //_cFont.textFormat->SetLineSpacing(DWRITE_LINE_SPACING_METHOD_UNIFORM, fontSize, 20.f);
                //_cFont.textFormat->SetTextAlignment(DWRITE_TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);


                SAFE_RELEASE(_cFont.textLayout);
                //For string update
                hr = _cFont.writeFactory->CreateTextLayout(
                    text,
                    textSize,
                    _cFont.textFormat,
                    0.0f,
                    0.0f,
                    &_cFont.textLayout
                    );
                IF_HR(hr);

                unsigned int uintTextSize = (UINT32)textSize;
                DWRITE_TEXT_RANGE allText = { 0, uintTextSize };
                _cFont.textLayout->SetFontSize(fontSize, allText);
                _cFont.textLayout->SetWordWrapping(DWRITE_WORD_WRAPPING_NO_WRAP);
            }

            _fontWrapper->DrawTextLayout(deviceContext, _cFont.textLayout, x, y, color, FW1_RESTORESTATE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what you want.

["`IDWriteTextLayout` interface" article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316718%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN says:

> The `IDWriteTextLayout` interface **represents a block of text after it has been fully analyzed and formatted**.

And ["Text Formatting and Layout" article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The text in an `IDWriteTextLayout` object **cannot be changed once the object is created**. To change the text you must delete the existing object and create a new `IDWriteTextLayout` object.

Comment: The reason I wanted to remove this in the first place is the fact that everytime I do this. I notice an increase in memory usage in runtime. (With the diagnostics tools for process memory.). When I do not continously recreate this textlayout. It stays (at the moment) 26MB. But with this creatingTextlayout, it increases 1 MB every 3 seconds

Comment: @413X If you're sure that increased memory footprint was caused by `IDWriteTextLayout`, may be you didn't release previous instances of the `IDWriteTextLayout` COM objects?

Comment: All my best efforts leads me to that statement to be the cause of it. I've added an edit in main post which shows the code in question.

Comment: @413X If a memory leak exists, it exists outside this code. At least I don't see it in code you've provided. I've also checked recreation of text layouts in my own application (using DWrite API directly, w/o 3rd party libraries) -- there's no memory leaks. Search a possible error outside this code.

Comment: @413X To create DWRITE_TEXT_RANGE for the entire text -- see advise of Dwayne Robinson here: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), at the bottom of the article.

Comment: I found a solution for the issue. Its still bytes being lost but its not an issue anymore. (So few it becomes irrelevant). Thanks for the help